# Is it possible to get all comments of a user From Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Api https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I am trying to get all the comments a specific user wrote. But I can't manage to find a way to do it.
Is it even possible and how ?

Comment: No there is no API for that.

Comment: @WizKid Isn't it possible to access them by the personal history if the user is logged ?

Comment: No there is not.